# How to get console to output something if a line of text is entered

Tags: c++, console

Sorry for bad title... don't know how else to describe it.  I am looking for a way to get console ( i'm using console until I can get sfml to work) to output something when a line of text is entered. For example, if i typed in " -gold " at any time, then it would print out the int gold that I defined. I have read stuff about scanners but I don't think that is what I want.

I will clarify if needed. Thanks.
Here is the code:

http://www.pastebin.ca/2970253

Comment: Could you please post your code?

Comment: Can you provide a small sample code snippet with the desired functionality? No matter, even if it doesn't work. Because, I am not able to understand anything from your explanation.

Comment: have you tried a debugger?

Answer (score 0):

You would need a loop, that reads your input and executes it as command.

```
while(true) {
cin>>cmd;
if(cmd=="-gold") cout<<"Gold: "<<endl;
...
}
```

Comment: Giving me the error: cmd was not declared in this scope. Do I need another #include ?

Comment: cmd is just a variable you are reading in ... name it however you want